# Unable to get the values for metaboxes for custom post type

Tags: custom-post-types, metabox

I am customizing this webpaint theme.I added repeater fields to the custom post "portfolio" using this great class by OHAD RAZ , link for the website is

```
https://en.bainternet.info/how-i-add-a-wordpress-metabox/
```

I have used this class many times with no problem at all.

This is the code being used to register and add meta boxes.

```
        add_action('init', 'create_portfolios');
        register_taxonomy("category_portfolio", array("portfolio"), array("hierarchical" => true, "label" => "Categories", "singular_label" => "Category", "rewrite" => true));

        function create_portfolios() {
            $portfolio_args = array(
                'label' => "Portfolio",
                'singular_label' => 'Portfolio',
                'public' => true,
                'show_ui' => true,
                'capability_type' => 'post',
                'hierarchical' => false,
                'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'portfolio', 'with_front' => true),
                'supports' => array('title', 'editor', 'thumbnail', 'author','excerpt'),
                'taxonomies' => array('post_tag'),              
                'show_ui'=>true,
                'query_var'=>true,
                'publicly_queryable'=>true,

            );
            register_post_type('portfolio',$portfolio_args);
        }

        /*Now we add the meta boxes to the services*/
        require_once( $templatepath."/meta-box-class/my-meta-box-class.php");

$config = array(
    'id' => 'stats',             // meta box id, unique per meta box 
    'title' => 'Statistics',          // meta box title
    'pages' => array('portfolio'),  // post types, accept custom post types as well, default is array('post'); optional
    'context' => 'normal',          // where the meta box appear: normal (default), advanced, side; optional
    'priority' => 'high',                // order of meta box: high (default), low; optional
    'fields' => array(),                 // list of meta fields (can be added by field arrays) or using the class's functions
    'local_images' => false,             // Use local or hosted images (meta box images for add/remove)
    'use_with_theme' => true            //change path if used with theme set to true, false for a plugin or anything else for a custom path(default false).
);
/*
* Initiate your meta box
*/

$my_meta = new AT_Meta_Box($config);

$repeater_fields[] = $my_meta->addTextarea($prefix.'re_textarea_field_id',array('name'=> 'Feature '),true);
$repeater_fields[] = $my_meta->addTextarea($prefix.'re_textarea_field_id1',array('name'=> 'Value '),true);


$my_meta->addRepeaterBlock($prefix.'re_',array('inline' => true, 'name' => 'Statistics','fields' => $repeater_fields));
/*
* Don't Forget to Close up the meta box deceleration
*/
//Finish Meta Box Deceleration
$my_meta->Finish();
```

And using this code to show the output for this custom post

```
$args = array(                      
           'post_type' => 'portfolio',           
      );
$loop = new WP_Query($args);
global $post;
if($loop->have_posts()):while($loop->have_posts()):$loop->the_post();
$stats = get_post_meta($post->ID, '_re', true);
var_dump($stats);


endwhile;
endif;
```

But i get nothing in the $stats.
Totally confused , please help

Comment: Why not post your question within the comments section of OHAD RAZ's website. He looks as if he is responsive to replying to comments. With that said your issue is 'get_post_meta($post->ID, '_re', true);' What is '_re'? Also when you created a text area for the class, what is $prefix? That is not defined which concatenates with a string to compile the field ID. Which should be the value of '_re'

Comment: @David Labbe i dont know, but this is the way how he  has told use his class and get the value for metaboxes